# SAML - IDP Initiated Example (Azure AD SAML Toolkit)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

The toolkit says: [Azure AD SAML Toolkit supports SP initiated SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/saml-toolkit-tutorial)

I have searched for IDP initiated examples, but the examples I find no longer are relevant.  I was hoping to use the toolkit, but it doesn't appear to allow this.  Can anyone please advise?  The Single Sign On option that is in some examples no longer exists in Azure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any.

IDP Initiated is started by the IDP and so is "built-in".

As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on). states:

"Sign-on URL    Required    Don't specify

When a user opens this URL, the service provider redirects to Azure AD to authenticate and sign on to the user. Azure AD uses the URL to start the application from Microsoft 365 or Azure AD My Apps.

When blank, **Azure AD does an IdP-initiated sign-on** when a user launches the application from Microsoft 365, Azure AD My Apps, or the Azure AD SSO URL".