# SAML IDP For Azure AD Lonin then redirect problem

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I customized an IDP according  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-services/dn641269(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

1. Send samlresponse to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf can login normally,this step is ok.
2. After logging in, I want to jump to other applications XXX, but whether I use the wreply or relaystate parameter, like

https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&whr=AAA&wreply=XXX

https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srfwa=wsignin1.0&whr=AAA&RelayState=XXX

Always redirect to the same address https://www.office.com/?auth=2, but **not XXX** after logging in. Is there a problem with me? Does login.srf support jumping to a user-defined address?

Comment: Have you tried giving this way  "?" instead of & >>  `?relayState=xxx`

Comment: I have tried according to your reply and still can't, thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like the request is using WS-federation protocol .RelayState does not work when the direct relying party is using WS-Federation.(That mightbe the reason for relaystate not being reflected)
2. The flow >> Identity provider STS -> WIF (WS-Fed) relying party App is not supported  by relay state parameter.
3. To use relaystate parameter, it must be IDP initiated SSO and the URL must be encoded . Configuration for SAML then should simply apply a randomstring parameter to the end of the URL. For example: ?relayState=xyz or &relayState=xyz (in some situations).

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on) and the references below.

**References:**

1. [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/ad-fs-2-0-relaystate#when-can-i-use-relaystate)
2. [techcommunity.microsoft.com reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/ad-fs-2-0-relaystate/ba-p/400145)
3. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868483/saml-idp-initiated-example-azure-ad-saml-toolkit)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try again with reference to the document